# Phone number link not clickable android

Tags: java, android, html

```
x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xLink);
x.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            AlertDialog x = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.this).create();

            x.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text)));

            x.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            x.show();

            return false;
        }
    });


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/xLink"
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/blue1"
    android:paddingTop="30dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="16dip" />

 <string name = "text">at&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href="tel:18004455667"&gt;1-800-445-5667 lt;/a&gt;.</string>
```

so basically when you click the link a dialog shows up, with the number in which appears to be a link but when you click, it does nothing.  Any reason this might be happening?  I already tried changing w/ out ascii characters but did nothing/

Comment: also tried android:autoLink="phone", didnt do anything either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer, it's tested.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);

        Spanned message = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text));
        final SpannableString str = new SpannableString(message);
        Linkify.addLinks(str, Linkify.ALL);

        builder.setMessage(str);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.create();

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                dialog.show();

                // This must be called after dialog.show();
                ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

                return false;

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, I tweaked it around to fit in my code better but thank you very much!  I do have one concern though;  After I added this, when I clicked on the phone number, the surrounding text would blink like the whole thing was a link.. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user1823974 you can vote the answer if it satisfies your needs :).

Comment: Tried, reputation is too low wont let me =/.  Ill come back to it when I get more points..

Comment: Do you know why the text would be flashing when clicked though.?

Comment: That should be a normal behaviour (it's a link), but try Linkify.addLinks(str, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);

Comment: Yes, but what I am trying to do is display a paragraph, with a phone number link at the end of it.  So to give you a better understanding of what I'm doing, I want a link on the main page that what you click it, a pop up appears and will say something like "for directions call 1800-222-4232.  So what that solution is doing is when you click the number "link" the whole paragraph flashes(except for the link itself for some reason which stays highlighted blue).  This looks funny to say the least and I can't find a way to fix it.  I tried putting "Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS" and the same result occured

Comment: That is very weird. I just tested it on 2 devices and the emulator. I don't get that behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the HTML anchor is the problem, especially if you didn't set the resource `text` with `fromHTML()` as in: `textView.setText(HTML.fromHTML(getString(R.string.text)));`

The easiest way to make a phone number clickable is `autoLink` and straight text:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:text="My Number: 1-800-762-2035"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the documentation at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

You may need to clean up your text as the garbage around it **may** be causing the problem.